# jquery $.when error when using version 1.8.3

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred

I am keeping a variable number of ajax promises in an array.
And when all promises are done I do something else:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then( function(){ 
    var myArgs = [];
    if(promises.length == 1){
        var myArgs = [];
        myArgs[0] = arguments;
    }else{
        myArgs = arguments;
    }

    for(i=0; i<myArgs.length; i++){
        fileArr[promise2File[i]]['prop1'] = myArgs[i][0].type;
        fileArr[promise2File[i]]['prop2'] = myArgs[i][0].message;
    }
});
```

When I am using jquery version 1.6.1 it works perfectly. However when I switch to a more recent version (1.8.3) I get the following js error when there are more than one ajax promise. It works fine with a single promise:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'progress'

I checked the type of the promisses variable to make sure it is array (with instanceof Array) and it is.

In case it is helpful this is how I fill the promises array:

```
var i = 0;

for(var file in fileArr){
    if (fileArr.hasOwnProperty(file)){
            if(fileArr[file].hasOwnProperty('status')){
                if($.inArray(fileArr[file]['status'], ['held','submitted']) !== -1){
                    promise2File[i] = file; // I need this to map each promise to the corresponding file
                    promises[i] = parent.myFunc('cancel', [file], false); //myFunc returns the ajax promise
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Any thoughts why I am getting this error on the newer version of jquery?

Comment: use .done instead of .then, it's functionality changed in later versions of jquery. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jQuery 1.8, that version of .then was removed and replaced with one that instead of accepting done/fail callbacks, accepts done/fail filters.

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Changing from .then to .done should solve your problem.

```
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function(){
```

`.then` after 1.8 is essentially the same as `.pipe` prior to 1.8

Comment: Kevin, that's all true but does it explain the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'progress'"? Maybe I'm being dumb but I can't see it.

Comment: With `.then()` as the last method of the chain, is it not academic whether it is pre/post 1.8?

Comment: To me, it seems more likely that `parent.myFunc()` returns a promise generated by a lib other than jQuery, and that pre-1.8 was somehow more tolerant of it.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot pre-1.8 `.then` didn't try to add callbacks to `.progress` unless you gave it a progress callback because the functionality of `.then` pre-1.8 was completely different. It is likely that myFunc returned a promise object from another library, but as long as it implements enough of the functionality jquery can handle it.

Comment: I thought I tried all the combinations ( [then, done] x [v1.6, v1.8] ) but I guess I haven't. Using .done with version 1.8 worked just fine.

Comment: @KevinB, thanks that all sounds very reasonable. I probably should have deleted my first two comments after posting the third but am encouraged that you concur with my "other lib" theory.